# this.innerHTML working fine if present in HTML button, but not working if kept in a separate javascript function

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="this.innerHTML=Date()">The time is?</button>
</body>
</html>
```

This is working fine.

But if I try to do the same thing by creating a separate JavaScript function, the code is not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

</head>
<body>

    <button onclick=displayDate()>The time is?</button>

    <script>
        function displayDate(){
            this.innerHTML=Date();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 6):

Your `this` isn't refer to the `button` itself, when it is in the `function` scope. You can achieve to the desired result with many approaches.

**1)** You can pass this to the function as a parameter

```js
function displayDate(context){
    context.innerHTML = Date();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="displayDate(this)">The time is?</button>
```

**2)** Using explicit bindings, like `call` or `apply`

```js
function displayDate(){
   this.innerHTML = Date();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="displayDate.call(this)">The time is?</button>
```

Comment: You should use the separate HTML and JS boxes in the snippet editor.

Comment: If this helps you, accept it and help others to find it

Answer (score -1):

You can try to do something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="test" onclick=displayDate()>The time is?</button>
  <script>
    function displayDate(){
      document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=Date();
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove "You can try to do something like this" out of the code block